# monodroid Having app continue to execute after minimizing app

Tags: android, xamarin.android, monodevelop, background-process, xamarin

I'm trying to put together a simple tracking app. All it does is register for location updates, than every 15 seconds it sends off the devices location to a webapi (web service) service. Here is the following code that does the register and post to server.

```
    #region START STOP TRACKING
    public void StartTracking()
    {
        if (currentAsset == null) { return; }
        isTracking = true;
        //SETUP THE LOCATION VARIALBES
        if (_geocoder == null) { _geocoder = new Geocoder(this); }
        if (_locationManager == null) { _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService); }

        var criteria = new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine };
        string bestProvider = _locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location lastKnownLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        //LOG RECORD FOR CURRENT LOCATION
        if (lastKnownLocation != null)
        {
            PostData(lastKnownLocation, DateTime.Now);
        }

        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 2000, 1, this);

        BusTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(delegate
        {
            var criteria = new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine };
            string bestProvider = _locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location lastKnownLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

            //LOG RECORD FOR CURRENT LOCATION
            if (lastKnownLocation != null)
            {
                PostData(lastKnownLocation, DateTime.Now);
            }

        });
    }
    public void StopTracking()
    {
        isTracking = false;
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
        BusTimer.Stop();
    }
    #endregion

    #region POST LOCATION DATA TO SERVER
    private void PostData(Location setLocation, DateTime setDate)
    {
        try
        {
            currentLocation = setLocation;
             string longString = string.Format("{0}", setLocation.Longitude);
            string latString = string.Format("{0}", setLocation.Latitude);

            //POST DATA OVER
            var client = new RestClient("http://mywebserver/");
            var request = new RestRequest("API/DataAPI/PerformAction", Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("ActionName", "PostEntityData"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
            string JSONString = "{'EntityID':" + currentAsset.AssetID.ToString() + ",'EntityName':'Asset','Long':" + longString + ",'Lat':" + latString + ", 'CheckDateTime':'" + setDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'}";
            request.AddParameter("ActionData", JSONString); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method         
            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);   
                this.RunOnUiThread(new Runnable(PostToastData));                                                       
            });                                                
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }                           
    }

     public void PostToastData()
     {             
         string longString = string.Format("{0}", currentLocation.Longitude);
         string latString = string.Format("{0}", currentLocation.Latitude);
         Toast.MakeText(this, "Logged Location record for " + currentAsset.AssetNumber + " at Long: " + longString + ", Lat: " + latString, ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }
    #endregion
```

This all works perfectly. And when I minimize the app it continues to post data off to the service correctly. The problem is after about an hour the app unexpectedly just dies.

Can anyone see any reason why it would crash after a certain amount of time? The application is barely using any ram so i wouldnt think it would be a memory issue. Should I be handling the app running in the background in a different manor? Should I be executing this process on a different thread so that it can continue to execute in the background when the app is not in focus?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue running things in the background after your app has lost focus, you should use a background service. Here are some links that should help you get started:

- [Background Services in Mono for Android](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/07/10/Background-Services-in-Mono-for-Android.aspx)
- [Creating Services](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Services)